# Simulator only Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

My project works for the Device, but for the simulator i'm getting 201 errors.
Here are a few of them:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50", referenced from:
      -[Controller createAdBannerView] in Controller.o
      -[iPadUniversalViewController createAdBannerView] in iPadUniversalViewController.o
 "_CGAffineTransformIsIdentity", referenced from:
      -[Texture2D(Image) initWithImage:] in Texture2D.o
  "_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[Controller showStaffSideways] in Controller.o
      -[Controller transitionAnimate] in Controller.o
  "_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      -[Controller createAdBannerView] in Controller.o
```

My project was working fine, I've tried re-adding frameworks, but it seems they aren't being seen by simulator.
Anyone know what gives?

Comment: Have you tried a clean and build? And clearing your derived data folder?

Comment: I had a similar issue today, be careful with this. When I clicked [] (stop) it wiped out a .h/.m oh my main view and half the code to my side views and then proceeded to shred my other files. Let's just say I now have to start from scratch on an app I have to have done and delivered by Sunday.